# Insert variable in subprocess.Popen

Tags: python

how can I pass the variable TargetFile in the Popen command?

```
import subprocess


TargetFile = 'D:/CG_CONTENT/TEXTURES/Concrete_Rough_ujxlfi2dy_4K_surface_ms/ujxlfi2dy_4K_Albedo.jpg'

subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"TargetFile"') #doesn't work
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Popen(["explorer", "/select", TargetFile])

Comment: Thanks. But it's opening the documents folder for some reason. 
```TargetFile = r'D:\CG_CONTENT\TEXTURES\Concrete_Rough_ujxlfi2dy_4K_surface_ms\ujxlfi2dy_4K_Albedo.jpg'

subprocess.Popen(["explorer", "/select", TargetFile])```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution I found.

```
import subprocess

TargetFile = r'D:\CG_CONTENT\TEXTURES\Concrete_Rough_ujxlfi2dy_4K_surface_ms\ujxlfi2dy_4K_Albedo.jpg'

subprocess.Popen(r'explorer /select,"'+TargetFile+'"')
```